# What function has a 3D graph that will look like a spiral into a singularity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions, 3d, polar-coordinates

I am trying to draw text spiraling into a black hole, from a more interesting slightly off-orthogonal viewpoint.

I think a function that defines a black hole/singularity surface might look something like z=-1/(x^2+y^2)... but I don't know how to get from that to a set of points (locations of letters) for my text that spirals into the singularity.

Thinking out loud I would want a decreasing radius and an increasing or decreasing angle value that wraps around 2*pi (or 360) and then translates each radius,angle into an x,y,z value...

so how is this?

- vary the radius from the largest value to the smallest value,
- vary the angle from 0 to 2*pi*(constant-number-of-spirals)
- vary the font size from largest value to smallest value
- x = cos(angle)*radius
- y = sin(angle)*radius
- z = -1/(x^2+y^2)

Will that work?
How would I get a tangent at each point to use as a baseline for each letter's "direction"?
Of course I will have to translate 3D to 2D to plot the letters...